# How to make waitForWebPageToLoad to work in coded ui test?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

First of all, i'm a beginner at coded ui testing and i have poor code skills but im trying to learn.

Right now i'm hand coding some test cases (c#) in visual studio (the record option is not enough for me) but i can't get the `waitForWebPageToLoad` to work.

So for example below, i click a link, enter some text and click a button. After that i would like the code to wait for the webpage to load before proceeding. What i have done now is a `Thread.Sleep` but that's not a good solution...

```
ClickLink(Repo.Link(Browser));
EnterText(Repo.Field(Browser), "12345789");
ClickButton(Repo.LeftButton(Browser));
Thread.Sleep(5000);  //<-------- This must be replaced... :)
```

How do i get the `waitForWebPageToLoad` function to work?
I have this methods but i can't understand how to make them work, anyone wanna help me understand?

```
void ClickButton(HtmlInputButton obj) {
    waitForWebPageToLoad(obj, 10);
    TestContext.WriteLine("Clicking button: " + obj.Name);
    Mouse.Click(obj);
}
```

### And:

```
void waitForWebPageToLoad(UITestControl parent, int waitTime) {
    waitTime = int.Parse(waitTime.ToString() + "000"); //waitTimeExtension.ToString());
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = waitTime;
    parent.WaitForControlExist(waitTime);
    parent.WaitForControlReady(waitTime);
}
```

Comment: Where did you get `waitTime = int.Parse(waitTime.ToString() + "000");` from? What is wrong with `waitTime *= 1000;`?

Comment: A colleague who is a developer helped me but he is not around in this project right now so im trying to figure this out the best i can

Answer (score 0):

The `waitforcontrol` kinda methods are called on a control type. And control exist would be true, but it doesn't mean that the control is ready (It probably be loading)

The general practice is call the waitforcontrolready method on the super parent. (Say Browser). I've modified your method as below,

```
 public void WaitForPageToLoad(BrowserWindow browser, int WaitTimeOut)
    {
        // Waiting on all threads enable to wait for any background process to complete
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
        // Wait 
        browser.WaitForControlReady(WaitTimeOut * 1000);
        // Revert the playback settings (As waiting on all threads may sometime have a toll on execution speed 
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
    }
```

then just call the method to wait, where ever you do a page load. Remember to pass browser and timeout in seconds as a parameter. Something like,

```
    ClickButton(Repo.LeftButton(Browser));
    WaitForPageLoad(Browser, 120);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks alot for your help Prageeth! I will test this later in the week probably and report back to you how it went :)

Comment: Hello again Prageeth Saravann. I have tried to implement and call your method now in my testcase but it seems to ignore the WaitForPageLoad(Browser, 120); call, or it might not been working? I changed to capital B in 'browser' in your modified method. Do you have any idea or more tips to get this working?

Comment: if you change the parameter.. then you will have to change it inside the method too. (Where it has browser.WaitForControlReady(WaitTimeOut * 1000);) And, did u debug the code ?

Comment: Yeah i tried debugging now with a breakpoint on WaitForPageLoad(Browser, 120); but im not sure exactly what to look for, is that code working for you?

Comment: It does.. Does the code flow wait for a second or so ? or it just passes ? What's exactly happening ?

Comment: Seems like it pass directly. I think it might be because the webbaplication is build in a certain way that makes only some windows in the application to load/refresh and not the whole Browser. Is it possible to modify the method you wrote to like, make it wait for ALL scripts in the browser to finish loading?