# Waiting for an application to fully load using CodedUI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, coded-ui-tests

So I'm using CodedUI to do some application testing, and I've got the test framework built out for the most part and everything individually seems to be working.

My issue is that events are happening before the application is entirely loaded, so it's essentially just clicking on a blank page.

I've used `Playback.Wait(x)` and that doesn't seem to do the trick.

I have also attempted to use, but most likely incorrectly, the `WaitForControlExist()` also with no real luck.

Extremely new to CodedUI, especially with what i'm using this for.  So any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT as per comments below:**
 Inside CodedUITest1.cs

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        this.UIMap.LaunchSoapUI();   //I WANT TO WAIT FOR THIS TO FULLY LOAD BEFORE GOING TO FindAndClickCustomFitNoRetest()
        this.UIMap.FindAndClickCustomFitNoRetest();
        this.UIMap.ClickPlayBtn();
        this.UIMap.EnterEmployeeID();
    }
```

Inside UIMap.Designer.cs

```
    public void LaunchSoapUI()
    {
        // Launch '%ProgramW6432%\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\SoapUI-5.3.0.exe'
        ApplicationUnderTest soapUI530Application = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(this.LaunchSoapUIParams.ExePath, this.LaunchSoapUIParams.AlternateExePath);
        WaitForAUTLoad(soapUI530Application, 120);
    }

    public void WaitForAUTLoad(ApplicationUnderTest aut, int WaitTimeOut)
    {
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
        aut.WaitForControlReady(WaitTimeOut * 1000);
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
    }
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: I've just posted a answer for this yesterday. See if that helps :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/41838745/5212566

Comment: @Prageeth I tried to implement it and it failed right at the call.

I'm using an ApplicationUnderTest rather than a browser, how would I change this up to work for me?

Answer (score 0):

**--ORIGINAL--**

**Load Wait Function:**

```
public void WaitForAUTLoad(ApplicationUnderTest aut, int WaitTimeOut)
{
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
    aut.WaitForControlReady(WaitTimeOut * 1000);
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
}
```

and can call like:

```
    ApplicationUnderTest soapUI530Application = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\SoapUI-5.2.1.exe");
    WaitForAUTLoad(soapUI530Application, 120);
```

I would invoke the method on a specific loading control, if the sync on the entire application does not yield expected result. You may also want to try methods like `WaitForControlPropertyEqual`

**--Edit PER OP Request --**

> It is never a best practice to edit designer.cs file as the changes
>   made to it will be lost. [See here on why!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670364/why-is-it-bad-to-edit-the-uimap-designer-cs-file-in-a-visual-studio-coded-ui-tes)

I would write a function on a separate .cs file. Some thing like,

```
public ApplicationUnderTest LaunchAUT(string exePath)
{
    return ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(exePath);
}
```

then call that on my Coded UI Test method

```
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        //Set path to SOAP UI Exe from your config 
        string SOAPUIExePath = @"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\SoapUI-5.2.1.exe";
        ApplicationUnderTest SoapUI = LaunchAUT(SOAPUIExePath);            
        WaitForAUTLoad(SoapUI, 120);
    }
```

Comment: I think i'm definitely still doing this wrong, it keeps failing at the method call.  I'm going to edit my original post with some code snippets and see if there's any insight to come from that.  Appreciate your help so far though.

Comment: Post the Error message, if you have any error. Updated my answer. To keep it short don't edit the designer.cs file. You changes will be lost!

Comment: Do I keep the `WaitForAUTLoad()` in a separate file as well? or should that belong in the CodedUITest1.cs file.

Comment: It's up to you. But a goof automation practice is to separate your reusable library to separate files.  Ex: you can have FunctionalLib.cs - where u store app related stuffs ApplicationLib.cs where you store application related functions. (like wait for AUT to load) etc.

Comment: Added an image of the stacktrace.  I have since created a separate class to hold those methods and calling them in my CodedUITestMethod1() prior to the events I want after the application has loaded.  Still no luck so far.

Comment: It appears to be something else. Let me try and update if I find something!

Comment: Sounds good.  For reference, I commented out the additional suggestions you've told me and reverted back to my original code and it seems to work (with the exception of I still need to wait for the application to load entirely).  Thank you kindly for taking so much time with this.